# Do I have to create extension methods if I want to add type constrained (T=int) method onto a generic (T) class?

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

for example, I have a (`non-static`) class `Foo<T>`

I would like to add a method `bar()` for `Foo`, however this method should only work for `Foo<int>`.

Because we cannot overload type constraints,
Do I have to create an extension method in a separate `static` class `bar(this Foo<int> myFoo)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, yes. C# (and the CLR in general) does not support template specialization known from C++.

Type parameters are meant to be used when your class'es implementation doesn't care about the actual type at all.

As an alternative, add a runtime check to make sure the method is only being called on `typeof(T) == typeof(int)`.